# How to hide iframe with FB Like button on click?

Tags: javascript, facebook, hide, onmouseup

I'm using this code (standard FB Like):

```
<div id="like"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

I need to hide the complete `div` (or `iframe`) when the user clicks on it.

I tried the `onclick` event but it didn't work inside `iframe`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="like"><iframe id="facebookFrame" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('facebookFrame').contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  // hide your iframe here or do whatever
  document.getElementById('facebookFrame').style.display = "none";
  alert("iframe was clicked");
}
```

Comment: I doubt that will be allowed by the browser

Answer (score 0):

I havent done it yet. Just found a good resource http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

maybe like that

```
parent.frames[1].location.href -> set to own url plus #anyanchor
```

so it wont be reloaded, then access the js function of main window

```
document.getElementById('facebookFrame').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistically I think that your best bet is to place *another*, this time transparent, `div` over the `iframe`. Set your click handler on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        your call back function to hide the iframe
});
```